# tracking pixel Magento with total excluding tax

Tags: php, magento

We have a pixel in our succes.phtml for one of our affiliate partners. In this mail we have the total and in the php snippet we get the grand total (grand_total). This one is including tax and including shipping costs.

How would we change the code below to get the total without tax and without shipping?

Hope someone can help.

```
<?php
  $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId(); 
  $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
  $order->load($lastOrderId); 
  $total = $order->getData('grand_total');
?>

<img src="http://www.domain.nl/tuin/img.php?campaignID=a1fddd&productID=8e7ba6&conversionType=sale&transactionID=<?php echo $this->getOrderId()?>&transactionAmount=<?= $total ?>&currency=EUR" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` has methods `->getGrandTotal()`, `->getTaxAmount()` and `->getShippingAmount()`. So you can change your code snippet like this:

```
  $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId(); 
  $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
  $order->load($lastOrderId); 
  $total = $order->getGrandTotal() - 
           $order->getTaxAmount() - 
           $order->getShippingAmount();
```